# Run time errors in eclipse for android.

Tags: android, eclipse, runtime-error

Is there a better way to find run time errors than using breakpoints?  I am used to visual studio that points out the lines and gives suggestions.  Maybe some code I can put in an alertdialog.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use logcat stacktrace (but you don't get data at the point of time), you can click on the stack trace which takes you to corresponding line in the file. Alert dialogs etc., are not possible.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do that